# If we let "a" be 2, and "x" be 1.4, we have the following

Tags: sentence-construction, mathematics

I want to know which of the following sentences sounds more natural and correct:

a + x = y

#1. If we **let** "a" **be** 2, and x **be** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

#2. If we **let** "a" **to be** 2, and x **to be** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

#3. If we **set** "a" **equals** 2, and x **equals** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

#4. If we **set** "a" **equal to** 2, and x **equal to** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

#5. If we **set** "a" **equals to** 2, and x **equals to** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

#6. If we **set** "a" **to** 2, and x **to** 1.4, we have the following: 2+1.4 = y

Other options are welcome.

Comment: They all seem too wordy unless this is intended for beginners in algebra.

Comment: Why are you putting quote marks around **a**? And only **a**?

Comment: Welcome! I encourage you to [take the tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for the kind of questions and answers that work well here. In particular, we want to avoid questions in which many answers are equally right or that invite answers that are lists. Note also that proofreading questions—questions that ask "is there anything wrong here"—are off-topic. If you have a specific concern about a particular usage, please edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Options 1 ("let **a** be 2"), 4 ("set **a** equal to 2"), and 6 ("set **a** to 2") are grammatically correct. There is another option: "let **a** equal 2."

Your other constructions are *not* grammatically correct.

I would avoid using "let" with the construction "If we." This implies that we are *allowing* or *permitting* the variable to equal that number, when instead we are *assigning* that value.
In the programming language LOGO the construction `let a equal 2` is proper. It can also be used if we are *setting up* some problem, like: "Let **a** equal 2 and **x** equal 1.4, then [blah blah blah]."

So I prefer "set **a** equal to 2" or "set **a** to 2."

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't speak in symbols, I would express this as...

> If *a* is equal to *two* and *x* is equal to *one point four*, then *y* is equal to *two plus one point four*, which is equal to *three point four*.

...but it is subjective.

I have intentionally swapped the *equals y* to *y is equal to* because putting the unknowns on the left-hand side of the equation feels more natural to me, when spoken; and I've taken the equation to its logical conclusion, using *which is equal to* to continue the calculation.

If your audience has a reasonable grasp of mathematics, they will parse and accept many short-hand forms, including the ones you have listed, especially if you are presenting it with the visual aid of the written equation.

*(original question was specific to speech)*

Comment: I would prefer '1.4' to 'one point four'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey :: the original question was specific to speech -- say "1.4" out loud

Comment: OK. Fair enough.